# How can i add mobile touch for my Dinosaur game on Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am editing Google Chrome's dinosaur game on unity. I want to run this game on mobile but I failed to add mobile touch. I want to only a touch function for this game. When I touch the screen it will jump or start a new game. (I don't need duck option.) I hope you guys help me.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class JumpAndDuck : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Level level = null;
    public GameObject ground = null;
    public Collider2D standingCollider = null;
    public Collider2D duckingCollider = null;
    public AudioSource jumpAudioSource = null;
    public AudioClip jumpAudioClip = null;
    private Animator animator;
    private bool grounded = true;
    private bool ducking = false;
    private float jumpVelocity = 0f;
    private float gravity = 144f;
    private Vector3 startVector;

    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        standingCollider.enabled = true;
        duckingCollider.enabled = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (grounded)
        {
            if (Input.GetButton("Jump") || Input.GetAxis("Vertical") > 0)
            {
                jump();
            }
            else if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") < 0)
            {
                duck();
            }
            else
            {
                stand();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position += jumpVelocity * Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime;
            jumpVelocity -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;

            if (transform.position.y < ground.transform.position.y)
            {
                grounded = true;
                transform.position = startVector;
                animator.SetBool("jumping", false);
            }
            else if (3 < transform.position.y && 20 < jumpVelocity)
            {
                jumpVelocity = 20;
            }
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject == ground)
        {
            grounded = true;
            transform.position = startVector;
            animator.SetBool("jumping", false);
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject == ground)
        {
            grounded = false;
            animator.SetBool("jumping", true);
        }
    }

    void jump()
    {
        if (!grounded)
        {
            return;
        }

        stand();
        if (jumpAudioSource && jumpAudioClip)
        {
            jumpAudioSource.PlayOneShot(jumpAudioClip, 1);
        }
        startVector = transform.position;
        jumpVelocity = 40f + level.mainSpeed / 10f;
        grounded = false;
        animator.SetBool("jumping", true);
    }

    void duck()
    {
        if (ducking || !grounded)
        {
            return;
        }

        standingCollider.enabled = false;
        duckingCollider.enabled = true;
        ducking = true;
        animator.SetBool("ducking", true);
    }

    void stand()
    {
        if (!ducking)
        {
            return;
        }

        standingCollider.enabled = true;
        duckingCollider.enabled = false;
        ducking = false;
        animator.SetBool("ducking", false);
    }
}
```

Code and project not mine. It is working well on PC with mouse clicks, I need to do it on mobile with touch function.

Comment: Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)  can be used for also touch. I mean come on. I found it on google ,30 seconds of my time.

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html) ?

Comment: Thank you i fix it now. You are right, this is so basic but i am new in here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            Debug.Log("Pressed left click.");

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
            Debug.Log("Pressed right click.");

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(2))
            Debug.Log("Pressed middle click.");

    }
}
```

You need to call this function from the Update function, since the state gets reset each frame. It will not return true until the user has released the mouse button and pressed it again. button values are 0 for left button, 1 for right button, 2 for the middle button.

URL: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html